# How to use the native pointer to a texture on the GPU?

Tags: c++, pointers, gpu, gpgpu

I'm currently doing some GPGPU on my GPU. I've written a shader that performs all the calculations I want it to do and this gives the right results. However, the engine I'm using (Unity), requires me to use a slow and cumbersome way to load the values from the GPU to the CPU, which is also memory-inefficient and loses precision. In short, it works, but it also sucks.

However, Unity also gives me [the option](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html) to retrieve the texture's ID (openGL specific ?), or the texture's pointer (not platform specific apparently), after which I can write a DLL in native code (c++), to get the data from the GPU to the CPU. On the GPU it's a texture in RGBAFloat (so 4 floats per pixel, but I could easily change this to just 1 float per pixel if that would be necessary), and on the CPU I just want a two-dimensional array of floats. It seems to me that this would be pretty trivial, yet I can't seem to find useful information.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can retrieve the floats in the texture using the pointer, and let C++ output it as an array of floats?

Please ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do it using shaders and a graphics engine? Doesn't your GPU support CUDA or OpenCL?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on exactly what you're asking. Is the issue getting the data back from the GPU? If so, you could look into using asynchronous PBO read back. That's a method OpenGL uses for getting your texture back to the CPU quickly and asynchronously. My impression is that it's the fastest way to do so on most systems.

Comment: It is worth noting that whilst it may be "cumbersome" to load the data via various "copy" or "map" operations, it is VERY expensive to do single data reads from the graphics processor to main memory or from the CPU to the GPU's memory, because you have a PCI/Express bus in between, which is quite a few clockcycles latency for each read. So it's not to be awkward that most of the systems that do this sort of thing require that you do stuff to copy the data over to the GPU's memory [and of course, the memory mapping of the GPU's memory and the CPU's map of the same memory may not match!]

Comment: @user1118321: the issue is indeed getting the data back from the GPU, where it is stored in a texture. All that my engine will give me is a pointer to that texture, and I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to do with that pointer.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I'm aware that single data reads are expensive because of the way the hardware works (separated VRAM and RAM, pipelines and stuff). However, I do have a texture with floats in them, and I want to get the total texture back to the CPU (where I will treat it as a two-dimensional array of floats and use it as a heightmap). It will therefor not be reading single values, but copying the total block to the CPU in one go.

Comment: Wait am I misunderstanding something but why do you need a pointer to the texture? Aren't there functions (OpenGL) that take the ID and read the data? Like glgetteximage?

Comment: Then there should be some sort of function (e.g. the OpenCL `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` that copy the data for you [at some point in the future from the call].